# Backbone.syphon and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, serialization, checkbox

Is it possible possible to return value from checkbox with Backbone.Syphon? Here is code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="pinky">
```

So when I do:

```
  var data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(this);
          this.model.set(data);
          this.model.save();
```

So that response would  be something like this:

```
{
 test: "pinky",
}
```

but not default 1 or 0 (true or false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick skim of [the documentation](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.syphon/blob/master/apidoc.md), there's a section about [defining custom input readers](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.syphon/blob/master/apidoc.md#syphoninputreaderset-input-readers). Your checkbox example might look like this:

```
Backbone.Syphon.InputReaders.register('checkbox', function($el){
    return $el.prop('checked') ? $el.val() : false;
});
```

This would return `{ 'test': 'pinky' }` if the checkbox is checked, and `{ 'test': false }` if it isn't.

Comment: Note: the official [backbone.syphon github](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.syphon) repo moved into the marionette tree.

Answer (score 0):

just bind a boolean variable (model) to the view, and on true return pinky and on false whatever...